# webpage looks different from apache under IIS

Tags: apache, iis

I run XAMPP/WAMP for programming on my local PC using PHP (+HTML). While on localhost everything is in order and the way it is supposed to be, IIS (thus, running Windows Server) screws things up.

**Example 1** - Checkboxes. The template I use has responsive checkboxes (radios also, and much more, applies to all the same way!). It's fine on localhost, however, on IIS, it looks the standard checkbox.

**Example 2** - Menu. The template I use supports expandable menus and navigation bars. It's fíne on localhost so that I can click the "main" item, and the dropdowns will appear. On IIS however, they're expanded when accessing the web page.

I guess there's something wrong with CSS? I'm also using Plesk. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not an issue of the http server, but apparently your css rules fail to load. Check the requests in the http server log. Also a look into the network tab of your browsers development console will show the issue.

Comment: thank you, you were right. http vs https. ;) thanks!

Comment: @JOHN post what you learned as an answer and accept it.